# Script file doesn't seem to work

Tags: shell

I had a bat file and I `converted` it into `script file`. But this file doesn't seems to work and give me error `line 45: syntax error: unexpected end of file` when I run it using
 `sh -x 1213.sh`

What is wrong with this file? Can anyone please help. I am new to this.

```
   set +v

if "$1"=="" printError 
if "$2"=="" printError 
if "$3"=="" printError 
if "$4"=="" printError 

export abc_env=$1
export type=$2
export filename=$3
export cutdate=$4


export abc_HOME=.
export LOG_BASE=.
export BATCH_SOURCE_DIR=.

export CLASSPATH=$abc_HOME\abc-batch\;$abc_HOME\lib\*;$abc_HOME\abc-batch\environment\
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH;$xyz_HOME\lib\thirdparty\*;$xyz_HOME\lib\*


export COMMAND=java -Dbatch.source.dir=$BATCH_SOURCE_DIR -Dsystem.dir=$LOG_BASE 
export COMMAND= $COMMAND -Dxyz.bootstrap.file=$abc_HOME$\abc-batch\environment\$xyz_BOOTSTRAP_FILE
export COMMAND= $COMMAND -Dxyz.settings=$abc_HOME\abc-batch\environment\$xyz_SETTINGS_XML


if "$type"="filter" $COMMAND com.lol.mib.risk.abc.batch.migration.Loader $filename $cutdate $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 
endHere

printError
echo on
echo ERROR - missing parameter.  Usage: loadFilterview [environment name] [filter|view] [path and name of input xls file] [cut-over date (dd-MMM-YYYY)

endHere
```

Comment: How did you convert bat file to script file?

Comment: @Thanos: I just did it manually looking at a post where for each bat symbol corresponding sh symbol was given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need changes in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

function printError()
{
    echo "Argument expected!"
}

#other struff

if [ "x$1" == "x" ]; then 
    printError 
fi

#other stuff
exit 0
```

Comment: Copy above code in `/tmp/test.sh`, run `chmod +x /tmp/test.sh` and then run `/tmp/test.sh`

Comment: Also note that `space` around `==` and `[` `]` are required

Comment: Glad to help you! :)